# Is it safe to integrate with SharePoint online API through a console application which is hosted on local VM

Tags: asp.net-core, console-application, sharepoint-online, office365api, azure-app-registration

I have the below console application, which integrates with SharePoint Online. the console application is hosted on a local VM and authenticates with SharePoint using ClientId, TenantID & Certificate, as follow:-

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PnP.Core.Auth;
using PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint;
using PnP.Core.Model.Teams;
using PnP.Core.QueryModel;
using PnP.Core.Services;
using PnP.Core.Services.Builder.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using static Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.MetricDimensionNames.TelemetryContext;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tenantId = "b***c";
            var clientId = "7*****9";
            var certificatePath = @"c:\CERT\SPDashBoardIntegration.pfx";
            var certificatePassword = "***";

            // Initialize a new service collection
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            // Load the certificate
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            // Configure logging
            serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddConsole();
            });

            // Add and configure PnP Core SDK
            serviceCollection.AddPnPCore(options =>
            {
                options.PnPContext.GraphFirst = true; // Set true if you prefer to use Graph over CSOM when possible
                                                      // options.HttpRequests.UserAgent = "ISV|Contoso|ProductX";
                options.Sites.Add("SiteToWorkWith", new PnPCoreSiteOptions
                {
                    SiteUrl = "https://********.sharepoint.com/sites/********-******",
                    AuthenticationProvider = new X509CertificateAuthenticationProvider(clientId, tenantId, certificate)
                });
            });
        int i = 0;
        // Build the service provider
        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Use the service provider to get the IPnPContextFactory instance
        var pnpContextFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPnPContextFactory>();

        // Now you can use the IPnPContextFactory to get a PnPContext and perform operations
        var context = await pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync("SiteToWorkWith");
        // Assume the fields where not yet loaded, so loading them with the list
        var workOrderList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Work Orders", p => p.Title,
                                                             p => p.Fields.QueryProperties(p => p.InternalName,
                                                                                           p => p.FieldTypeKind,
                                                                                           p => p.TypeAsString,
                                                                                           p => p.Title));
```

Now my question is if this is a secure approach? I mean when the VM sends the ClientID, Client Secret & Certificate to SharePoint Online, will that info be secure on the network? i mean will the console application communicate with SharePoint in a secure way when it sends the credentials (ClientID, Client Secret & Certificate)? If not, then how we can secure this?

Thanks

Comment: why i got a down vote? can you provide a reason so i can enhance the question  accordingly ?